# Improving my first Clojure program

Tags: clojure

After a few weekends exploring Clojure I came up with this program. It allows you to move a little rectangle in a window. Here's the code:

```
(import java.awt.Color)
(import java.awt.Dimension)
(import java.awt.event.KeyListener)
(import javax.swing.JFrame)
(import javax.swing.JPanel)

(def x (ref 0))
(def y (ref 0))

(def panel
  (proxy [JPanel KeyListener] []
    (getPreferredSize [] (Dimension. 100 100))
    (keyPressed [e]
      (let [keyCode (.getKeyCode e)]
        (if (== 37 keyCode) (dosync (alter x dec))
        (if (== 38 keyCode) (dosync (alter y dec))
        (if (== 39 keyCode) (dosync (alter x inc))
        (if (== 40 keyCode) (dosync (alter y inc))
                            (println keyCode)))))))
    (keyReleased [e])
    (keyTyped [e])))

(doto panel
  (.setFocusable true)
  (.addKeyListener panel))

(def frame (JFrame. "Test"))
(doto frame
    (.add panel)
    (.pack)
    (.setDefaultCloseOperation JFrame/EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
    (.setVisible true))

(defn drawRectangle [p]
  (doto (.getGraphics p)  
    (.setColor (java.awt.Color/WHITE))
    (.fillRect 0 0 100 100)
    (.setColor (java.awt.Color/BLUE))
    (.fillRect (* 10 (deref x)) (* 10 (deref y)) 10 10)))

(loop []
  (drawRectangle panel)
  (Thread/sleep 10)
  (recur))
```

Despite being an experienced C++ programmer I found it very challenging to write even a simple application in a language that uses a radically different style than what I'm used to.

On top of that, this code probably sucks. I suspect the globalness of the various values is a bad thing. It's also not clear to me if it's appropriate to use references here for the x and y values.

Any hints for improving this code are welcome.

Comment: I'm working on learning clojure too.  Thanks for the question and working code sample.

Comment: @mcotton, glad you find it helpful. Perhaps these notes are useful too: http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/c16rr/clojure_notes/

Comment: I love this program!  When running it under leiningen, I occasionally get `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching clause: 157`, whether running it via `lein run` or via `lein uberjar`.  I have no idea where this error is coming from.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those `if`s in `keyPressed` can be replaced with a single `case`. Also, the `dosync` can be moved outside to wrap the `case`. In fact, `alter` can be moved out too, so that if you e.g. decide to change it to `commute`, there's just the one place to make the change. The result:

```
(def panel
  (proxy [JPanel KeyListener] []
    (getPreferredSize [] (Dimension. 100 100))
    (keyPressed [e]
      (let [keyCode (.getKeyCode e)]
        (dosync
         (apply alter
           (case keyCode
             37 [x dec]
             38 [y dec]
             39 [x inc]
             40 [y inc])))
        (println keyCode)))
    (keyReleased [e])
    (keyTyped [e])))
```

You could also rewrite the imports more concisely:

```
(import [java.awt Color Dimension event.ActionListener])
(import [javax.swing JFrame JPanel])
```

-- whether you'd want to is a matter of style.

I would rename `drawRectangle` to `draw-rectangle` (that's the idiomatic style for function names in Clojure) and, more to the point, rewrite it as a pure function accepting the coordinates as explicit arguments. Then you could write a small wrapper around that to use your Refs, if indeed your design would benefit from the use of Refs. (Hard to say without knowing how you might want to use & modify them etc.)

Prefer `while` to `(loop [] ... (recur))` (see `(doc while)` and `(clojure.contrib.repl-utils/source while)`).

Also -- and this is important -- **don't put anything except definitions at top level**. That's because top-level forms are actually executed when the code is compiled (try loading a library with a `(println :foo)` at top level). That infinite loop should be wrapped inside a function; the standard name for a "main" function in Clojure is `-main`; same goes for `panel` and `frame`. This doesn't apply when playing around at the REPL, of course, but it's an important gotcha to know about.

Incidentally, `(doto foo ...)` returns foo, so you can just write `(doto (proxy ...) (.setFocusable true) ...)`.

Otherwise, I'd say the code is fine. Normally you'd want to put it in a namespace; then all the imports would go in the `ns` form.

HTH

Comment: I think that you either have to define your own `case` or go with `(condp = keyCode ...)`. Or is there a `case` somewhere in the standard Clojure libs?

Comment: Oh, apparently it's been added post-1.1. Thanks for catching that! And of course the right solution for 1.1 is indeed to use `(condp = ...)` (actually even in 1.2 if there are hash collisions between test expressions, see http://www.assembla.com/spaces/clojure/tickets/296).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I actually thought it was a feature from previous versions obsoleted by `condp` in 1.1 :-)

Comment: Why 'Prefer `while` to `(loop [] ... (recur))`' ? Can you elaborate on your reasoning for making this statement?

Answer (score 5):

Edit, while writing the below post in a hurry I forgot to say you must not put parens around constants eg java.awt.Color/WHITE.

In addition to Michał's comments:

- when you use an infinite loop, condition it with an atom (eg @switch) thus you'll be able to stop it (unless the loops runs on the repl thread -- so lauch it in a separat thread with  "future")
- you use refs, so it means the values of x and y are intended to be coordinated (in your code they are not: each update is independent); hence in drawRectangle you should wrap the reads in a dosync to be sure that you get a consistent view -- again in your actual code it doesn't matter because x and y are always updated independently.

hth,

(shameless plug: http://conj-labs.eu/)

Answer (score 3):

Although not exactly Clojure advice - consider using KeyAdapter instead of KeyListener. That way you won't have to provide empty implementations for keyReleased and keyTyped. It's generally a good rule to use adapter classes when you're not needing all of the methods of a Listener interface.