# tracking down AWT exception in Clojure UI app under Leiningen

Tags: clojure, awt, leiningen

Referring to this SO [question on a first UI program in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792451/improving-my-first-clojure-program), I created a new `Leiningen` app project:

```
lein new app a-ui-app
```

copied the source into the `core.clj` that leiningen generated and modified the `-main` routine to call it

```
(defn -main
  "See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792451/improving-my-first-clojure-program?rq=1."
  [& args]
  ;; work around dangerous default behaviour in Clojure
  (alter-var-root #'*read-eval* (constantly false))

  (doto panel
        (.setFocusable true)
        (.addKeyListener panel))

  (doto frame
        (.add panel)
        (.pack)
        (.setDefaultCloseOperation JFrame/EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
        (.setVisible true))

  (loop []
        (draw-rectangle panel @x @y)
        (Thread/sleep 10)
        (recur))
  )
```

I then run it via either

```
lein run
```

or

```
lein uberjar
java -jar ./target/a-ui-app-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

In both cases, the app works well, but in the terminal that I used to start it up, I get an exception after a random delay of several seconds:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching clause: 157 at
>   a_ui_app.core$fn__16$fn__21$fn__22.invoke(core.clj:19) at
>   clojure.lang.AFn.call(AFn.java:18) at
>   clojure.lang.LockingTransaction.run(LockingTransaction.java:263) at
>   clojure.lang.LockingTransaction.runInTransaction(LockingTransaction.java:231)
>   at a_ui_app.core$fn__16$fn__21.invoke(core.clj:17) at
>   a_ui_app.core.proxy$javax.swing.JPanel$KeyListener$6c415903.keyPressed(Unknown
>   Source) at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6340) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2809) at
>   a_ui_app.core.proxy$javax.swing.JPanel$KeyListener$6c415903.processKeyEvent(Unknown
>   Source) at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6159) at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2083) many more
>   lines...

I made no changes to `project.clj` -- just used the leiningen-generated one.

I'd like to understand what's going on.  I am by no means knowledgeable in Java Threading.  Is the problem related to the way leiningen launches the app's Java threads?  Is it unavoidable?  If not, how can I fix it, both for this little sample program and going forward, as a project pattern for future projects using the UI thread (which I think is `AWT-EventQueue-0`).

Comment: On a side note, does anyone know what's the effect of the first line (alter-var-root etc)? It generated by lein new app _

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you get precisely that error but I'd say you're doing several things incorrectly: Swing is a complicated beast ; )

Swing is not thread-safe.  The "rules" as to what you could and couldn't do on the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread / UI Thread) changed over time... At some point Sun decided that everything modifying Swing components should be done on the EDT.

So drawing your rectangle from another thread busy doing a spinning loop is a big no-no. Also the way you do your drawing isn't correct: you're not supposed to directly go fetch the Graphics object and modify it from your other thread (that's kind a super hack and should trigger crazy blinking).  One "correct" Swing way of doing it is to override the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` Java method and do your drawing there: so everytime that component needs to be redrawn, it's going to be redrawn correctly.

Here's a modified version of your code (I didn't fix the nested if statements which should be a case etc.) using *paintComponent* to draw the rectangle:

```
(import java.awt.Color)
(import java.awt.Dimension)
(import java.awt.event.KeyListener)
(import javax.swing.JFrame)
(import javax.swing.JPanel)

(def x (ref 0))
(def y (ref 0))

(def panel
  (proxy [JPanel KeyListener] []
    (paintComponent [g]
      (proxy-super paintComponent g)
      (doto g
        (.setColor (java.awt.Color/WHITE))
        (.fillRect 0 0 100 100)
        (.setColor (java.awt.Color/BLUE))
        (.fillRect (* 10 @x) (* 10 @y) 10 10)))
    (getPreferredSize [] (Dimension. 100 100))
    (keyPressed [e]
      (let [keyCode (.getKeyCode e)]
        (if (== 37 keyCode) (dosync (alter x dec))
        (if (== 38 keyCode) (dosync (alter y dec))
        (if (== 39 keyCode) (dosync (alter x inc))
        (if (== 40 keyCode) (dosync (alter y inc))))))
        (.repaint this)
        ))
    (keyReleased [e])
    (keyTyped [e])))

(def frame (JFrame. "Test"))

(defn -main [& args]

  (doto panel
        (.setFocusable true)
        (.addKeyListener panel))

  (doto frame
        (.add panel)
        (.pack)
        (.setDefaultCloseOperation JFrame/EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
        (.setVisible true)))
```

I'm not a big fan of `deref`'ing x and y separately: but AFAICT both `paintComponent` and the key listener trigger are guaranteed to happen on the EDT so the readings in your case should be consistent.  I'd still use a single `xy` def if I were you.

I'm also a bit perplex regarding the JPanel which is also a KeyListener and the -main function which then adds the KeyListener to himself: `(doto panel (.addKeyListener panel))` just feels weird.  It may be ok, I don't know: it just feels weird : )

Now regarding your exception I don't know but the Swing EDT actually throws exceptions once in a while because Swing has quite a few bugs *and* because Swing is so complicated to use correctly that programs tend to make quite a few honest mistakes. Depending on the platform/JVM either the exception is caught and the EDT keeps running **OR** a new EDT is automagically started.  Normally you shouldn't be able to "crash" the EDT, because should the EDT crash it should restart automatically.  That's why you're seeing the exception yet you're saying your program still "works well".

I'd say that exception and the cryptic stack trace is related to Swing not being thread-safe and you doing weird things: spinning loop fetching the panel's underlying Graphics object and messing with it but I'm really not sure.

Your code with the modification above seems to be doing what you want to do finely and without blinking.

Hope it helps.